# How to find the eigen values and eigen vectors of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the eigen values and eigen vectors of the system

$ \begin{align}  \frac{dx}{dt}=-ax+ay \\ \ \frac{dy}{dt}=bx-y \ \ \ \ \  \end{align} $

Where $ a>0 \ $. Discuss the cases $ \ \ b=1 , \ \ b< 1 , \ \ b>1 \ $. Further sketch the direction field .

**Answer:**

I found the Eigen values as follows :

$ \lambda=\frac{-(1+a) \pm \sqrt{(1+a)^2-4(1-b)}}{2} \ $

For $ \ b=1 \ $ , we have

$ \lambda=0 , \ \ -(1+a) \ $

But how can I discuss the other cases and find the Eigen vectors?

It becomes complicated .

I need help doing this.

Comment: How ?  You just calculate to see that $ 0  \ \ , -(1+a) \ $ are the eigen values when $ b=1 \ $

Comment: you find find using $ b=1 \ $  and check that you are wrong .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ that you calculated for

$$\left[\boldsymbol{A}-\lambda_i\boldsymbol{I}\right]\boldsymbol{v}_i=\boldsymbol{0}.$$

And solve for the components of $\boldsymbol{v}_i$.

Comment: I know that but the problem is if $ b \neq 1 $ , then the expression becomes complicated . In that cases how to find the corresponding eigen vectors .

Comment: can you help for $ b<1 \ $ ? and find the eigen vectors